# Archiving/migrating a WordPress blog to a new subdomain using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

### ***Background***

Let's call the domain in question `mydomain.com`.

I've been running a blog for a few years that I'd like to retire so I can use the domain for other things.

All blog posts on this domain have URLs prepended by `/blog/`. So my goal is to archive/migrate `mydomain.com/blog/*` to `archive.mydomain.com/blog/$1`

**Caveat:** Under a subdomain, I run another blog that I would **not** like to affect or change.

Let's call this `important_blog.mydomain.com`.

### **What I'm trying to achieve**

- Current requests to any URL beginning with `mydomain.com/blog/*` should be **301**-redirected to `archive.mydomain.com/blog/$1`.

  - Assume that I will a) update my DNS records, b) move files around and b) change WordPress settings to accommodate this.
- New requests made to anything *other* than `/blog/` or `important_blog.mydomain.com/*` should be treated as normal, i.e. not be redirected.

### **What I'm trying to figure out**

What should the contents of `mydomain.com/.htaccess` be for this to happen?

### **Epilogue**

The idea is to run this setup so that Google and other search engines are happy and have re-routed their entries for the old blog to the `archive` subdomain.

Then I will remove the `/blog/` redirect and run a different blog on the main domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier than I thought. Move all files over to `/archive`, update the `wp_options` setting in the database relating to `site_url` and `home` and add this to the standard WordPress `.htaccess` file, above all rules but below the `RewriteBase`.

```
RewriteRule     ^/blog/(.*) archive/blog/$1 [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

This performs the following steps:

1. Checks if the URL matches the pattern of containing `/blog/`, irrespective of case (`NC`). The two forward slashes ensures it doesn't capture e.g. `blog` as part of a term in the URL.
2. If this is true, it will do a 301-redirect (`R=301`) without escaping any characters (`NE`)
3. **Key:** The above is run as the last (`L`) rule, preventing any of the default WordPress rules to be run.